# yii2 image is uploaded but not saved in db

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I want to save my image in db it is uploaded but not saved in my database any one know how to fix this

```
 public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $fname = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
            if (!empty($fname)) {
                $temp_path = Yii::$app->basePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                $model->save();
                $fname->saveAs($temp_path . $fname);
                $model->imageFile = $fname->name;

                //  echo '<pre>'; print_r($fname->name);
                //exit();
            }

            if ($model->save()) { // To save the title to the database
                Yii::$app->getSession()->addFlash('success', 'Image uploaded');
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                        'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you defined rule for `imageFile` ? And why `$model->save();` two times. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: yes i have make mistake in model defined public $imageFile therefore it was not working thanks for given time